# How to get progress of ZipFile.Read()

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm using this code ;

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(FileName))
{
    zip.ExtractProgress += ExtractProgressHandler;    
    zip.ReadProgress += ReadProgressHandler;
    zip.ExtractAll(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Library\\" + zip.Comment,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);               
}
```

But ReadProgress event never fires. I think i need to add event handler before using ZipFile.Read(). But i don't know how to do.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in ReadProgressHandler?

Comment: @abatishchev It is DotNetZip. The BCL ZipFile class does not have events.

Comment: @Onots: ok, thanks, just was curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the overloaded ZipFile.Read that takes ReadOptions. You can specify the event handler in the ReadOptions.

```
ReadOptions myReadOptions = new ReadOptions { ReadProgress = ExtractProgressHandler };
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(FileName, myReadOptions))
{
    zip.ExtractProgress += ExtractProgressHandler;    
    zip.ExtractAll(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Library\\" + zip.Comment,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);               
}
```

Note: I didn't test it, code provided as is.